# In Ruby on Rails, non-deterministic data returned from DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I tried a line:

```
last_item = Item.last
last_item.created_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

and the SQL in the console log is:

```
SELECT "items".* FROM "items" ORDER BY items.id DESC LIMIT 1
```

BUT sometimes I get `2011-04-03`, and sometimes, `2011-04-04`

that is really strange.  If I print the time out, it is

> Sun, 03 Apr 2011 17:58:48 UTC +00:00

what give Rails 3  (3.0.5) this non-deterministic behavior?  Is it Time Zone?  But I am pressing Reload in the browser and it gives 04-03 this time and next time it gives 04-04 without restarting the server or changing any config file or source code.

---

**Update:** further debugging show that when it is 04-04, then the time printed using `p last_item.created_at` is:

> Mon, 04 Apr 2011 01:58:48 HKT +08:00

but I have this line in the view:

```
- Time.zone = 'Hong Kong'
```

but the `last_item.created_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` was done in the controller.  So shouldn't the controller run first, and in the view, I am merely trying to print it using a different Time zone... also, why will it sometimes become UTC, and sometimes HKT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that setting the time zone in the view could cause this non-deterministic behavior.  You should try setting your time zone somewhere in the config directory, perhaps in `config/application.rb`.

Comment: but what if that is set in the config file, and in the view, I want Hong Kong time, and when doing Database query, I want local time (or UTC time), so I will need to do Time.zone = '...' right before I call strftime()?  What if it is non-deterministic even right after I set it, it is set to something else -- if it is non-deterministic, there can be a chance that it can be reset to whatever in the config file, at any time?

Comment: If I recall correctly, the way the Ruby time libraries are designed, you should pick your "local" time zone at the start of your program, and from then on the only kind of DateTime objects you are allowed to have must be in UTC or must be in local time.  Look at the functions available on DateTime: .utc and .local.  They don't have generic functions for converting between timezone X to timezone Y.  If you want to use a bunch of different time zones then I think you'll have to add or subtract a couple hours from your DateTime just before printing it.  Don't set Time.zone in the view.